# Do signals create new threads?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I'm trying to understand how the signals/slots work within a GUI program. For example, if a slot in the main program gets a signal, does it create another thread to handle the slot?

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void finished_result(int);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread* thread;
    Worker* worker;

private slots:
    void run_click();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::run_click(){
    thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(task_finished(int)),this,SLOT(finished_result(int)));
    // all other necessary signal/slot connections
    thread->start();

    // do more stuff
}

void MainWindow::finished_result(int x){
    // do some stuff
}
```

In a program such as this, say the "do more stuff" take a while to process and the worker finishes the work before `run_click()` returns. So `run_click()` will be still running when `task_finished(int)` is emitted. Will `finished_result(int)` start immediately or will it wait for `run_click()` to finish? Will `finished_result(int)` start in the same thread as `run_click()` or in a new thread?

My particular problem is I have an unrelated `QWaitCondition` in my "do more stuff" which holds that thread for a while. I want my `finished_result(int)` to go ahead without waiting for `run_click()` to finish. Any ideas how to proceed? Will I need to move "do more stuff" to another worker in a new thread?

Comment: Is it possible to move the "do more stuff" into it's own worker thread? That way, the `QWaitCondition` will still pause it till it's time to do work but it will allow the main thread to return to the event loop immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, signals never create new threads.

In your case, `run_click()` and `finished_result(int x)` will be performed in the same thread, and in this order. When the signal `task_finished(int)` is emitted from your worker thread, it will be transferred and wait in a queue of your main thread, waiting for `run_click()` to finish and hence return to the event loop. Only then `finished_result(int x)` will be called.

This is called "Queued Connection" and is the default behaviour when using signals and slots accross different threads. Have a look at [Threads and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) from the documentation for more info, in particular the section [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Answer (score 1):

Good answer from Boris (+1)

I would just add for your second question, where you want finished_result() to be handled without waiting for run_click() then you would need to put that into another thread (and connect it all up) if you want it to run "safely".

You may read that Qt does allow you to force the connection to be a "DirectConnection" where the signal is handled as soon as it is received, this is default for signal within the same thread, but to do this accross threads is very dangerous, so don't be tempted by that option!

There might be a third option to pause the current event and find the next item on the event queue.. but I am not sure about that, I thought I read somthing like this a while back but can't find it... maybe someone can answer that part? (I'll take a look see if I can find this).

Comment: +1 I completely agree with the first two paragraphs. (And realize I completely skipped that part of the question XD). I never heard about what you talk about in the last part, but even if this is possible, going with another thread still seems a much better approach.

Comment: @Boris Yeah, I did not find anything about "option 3", I think it may only exist in my head! ... I know you can do certain things directly with the event queues, but to effectivly "switch" (put what you are doing on the queue and start on the next item).... probably not :(

Comment: Anyway it was good to mention, I never played with the event queue myself. I don't think I'll have a practical need any soon, but it looks interesting so I'll probably try to play around this when I have some spare time :-P